# Implementing a learning rate warm up and a learning rate schedule using pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I’m trying to implement both a learning rate warmup and a learning rate schedule within my training loop.

I’m currently using [this](https://github.com/Tony-Y/pytorch_warmup) for learning rate warmup, specifically the `LinearWarmup()`. So this simply ramps up from `0` to `max_lr` over a given number of steps.

I’m also wanting to use `CosineAnnealingWarmRestarts(optimizer, T_0, T_mult)` as my lr scheduler.

The challenge is that I’m wanting to use a rather long warm up period, without using an initially high value of `T_0`. Is there a way I can set the LR scheduler to become active only after `X` number of steps have passed? A simplified version of my code is below. I would also like the option of having the lr remain static after the warmup for a specified number of steps before the decay schedule begins.

If my initial value of `T_0` is not high enough, the LR value during the warm up period follows the pattern of the LR schedule.

```
import torch
import pytorch_warmup as warmup

optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(params, lr=lr)
num_steps = len(dataloader) * num_epochs
lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingWarmRestarts(optimizer, T_0=10, T_mult=2)
warmup_scheduler = warmup.LinearWarmup(optimizer, warmup_period=1000)
iters = len(dataloader)
for epoch in range(1,num_epochs+1):
    for idx,  batch in enumerate(dataloader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = ...
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        with warmup_scheduler.dampening():
            lr_scheduler.step(epoch + idx / iters)
```